# Java String in UDF Issue for novices

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

Having done this below and having read the stuff about companion objects, which I can't really say I follow in the year 2018 and can explain to others well:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val myUDf = udf((s:String) => Array(s.trim.replaceAll(" +", " "))) // <----

//error: object java.lang.String is not a value --> use Array

val data = List("i  like    cheese", "  the dog runs   ", "text111111   text2222222")
val df = data.toDF("val")
df.show()

 val new_df = df
  .withColumn("udfResult",myUDf(col("val")))
  .withColumn("new_val", col("udfResult")(0)) // <----
  .drop("udfResult")                          // <----

 new_df.show
```

Is there a more elegant way to get rid of the `Array` in this and somehow use String?

Comment: dont see the mark down as being relevant when discussed with others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the definition of `myUdf` itself. There is no need to wrap the String into an array:

```
val myUDf = udf((s: String) => s.trim.replaceAll("\\s+", " ")) // <-- no Array(...)
```

Then there is no need to play with columns excessively:

```
val new_df = df.withColumn("new_val", myUDf(col("val")))

+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 val|             new_val|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|   i  like    cheese|       i like cheese|
|     the dog runs   |        the dog runs|
|text111111   text...|text111111 text22...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: it was explained to me differently in the past, but I am impressed and enlightened